# Can I change tmux status bar color when I hit C-b

Tags: tmux, colors, highlighting

I use tmux on the local computer then ssh and use tmux too.

I can easily use them both (C-b twice for modifying the second tmux) but for more readability I'd like to highlight the status bar of the tmux I'm on

What I'd like to achieve is when I hit C-b once the first status bar change and when I hit it twice the second one change (I don't really care if the first one stay change or not).

I didn't found anything helpfull concerning color change when C-b is hit so I'm wondering if this even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it looks like your best bet is to start with the format variable `client_prefix` when you define your status line.

For your reference, there's a solid answer to a similar question on SO by Chris Johnsen that you might reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003726/give-a-hint-when-press-prefix-key-in-tmux

This is a good question, and would prove to be a very useful addition to my workflow. I'm going to see about getting something like this rolled into [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline), which is what I use for my `tmux` statusbar.

**EDIT**: Pull request submitted for adding this feature to powerline. I configured only the session block to change colors if the prefix becomes active: https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/pull/863

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for pointing me this :)